# FTP User Isolation with Server 2012 R2

Tags: ftp, iis-8

I have a WS12R2 with one FTP site,  and I want to enable the user isolation for the users. However, it's instead of try to use the %FTPRoot%\LocalUser\%Username% folder, it's looking for the %FTPRoot%\%MachineName%\%Username% folder, then ending with the "usual" 530 error if something is wrong. But, it shouldn't be look for %ComputerName% folder, the server is not even a domain-joined machine. I already started the configuration from scratch, however, the result is the same. On any other machines, the same configuration working fine (Looking for the "LocalUser" folder).

Any suggestions? Anybody else met with this issue?

Thanks,

Andras

Answer (score 1):

Just for records:

After multiple IIS full reconfiguration, the issue was still there, and looked for the %ComputerName% folder instead of LocalUser.

I renamed the machine, and without touching the IIS, the FTP started to work normally. I'm not sure what is stuck and where, but that solved my issue.

Thanks for the help anyways! :)

Andras

Comment: I can confirm this also worked for me.